# Send signal when attributes modified - QGIS 2.6

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, plugins

For a QGIS 2.6 python plugin, I am trying to send a signal when an attribute value is changed (values for an existing feature are updated or added and the attribute form dialog is accepted). This signal should then connect to another function. Note, that the feature is not being added (it already existed, and attributes are being modified after identifying a feature while in edit mode). This is why the `featureAdded` signal doesn't work.

So far, i've tried using `attributeValueChanged`, `editCommandEnded` and `layerModified` signals from the [vector layer class](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html)  in this way with no success.

```
def myFunction(self):
    self.myLayer.attributeValueChanged.connect(self.myOtherFunction)

def myOtherFunction(self):
    self.myLayer.dostuff
    self.dlg.show()
```

Comment: Have a look at this one http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108869/get-signal-on-edited-feature about a few good events. Your myOtherFunction needs some arguments to match to the slot correctly *QgsFeatureId fid, int idx, const QVariant &*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the `attributeValueChanged` SIGNAL in a created-from-scratch test plugin using QGIS v.2.6.1

You can connect the SIGNAL to your slot this way (I did it in my `run()` method):

```
def run(self):
    self.lyr = self.iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0]
    self.lyr.attributeValueChanged.connect(self.mySlot)
```

And then, you have two options to write your slot (see `mySlot` and `mySlot2`):

```
def mySlot(self):
    QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(), "Test", 
        "Attributes were changed!!!", QMessageBox.Ok )

def mySlot2(self, fid, idx, v):
    QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(), "Test", 
        "Attributes changed for feature " + str(fid), QMessageBox.Ok )
```

Both slots work, just replace `self.mySlot` by `self.mySlot2` in the connect method above if you want to switch between them.

If you want to get the test plugin, run it on your QGIS, and have a look at the code, you can access to it [here](https://github.com/gacarrillor/test/tree/attribute_value_changed). You find installation and usage instructions in the README file.

Comment: I just got it working, too, for something similar to mySlot2. An implementation like mySlot, however, didn't connect properly.

Comment: @user25976 Added a link to the plugin if you want to test in on your environment. Both slots should work.

Answer (score 1):

So the event that works IS attributeValueChanged. I simply needed to add some arguments to my function, as mentioned by another user. This works now:

```
def myFunction(self):
    self.myLayer.attributeValueChanged.connect(self.myOtherFunction)

def myOtherFunction(self, fid, idx):
    self.myLayer.dostuff
    self.dlg.show()
```