# Passing layer that caused signal to another function with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I've been searching for a while to find a way to pass the layer that caused a signal to another function.   I have a list of layers that that I want to apply automated attributes to.   This has complicated this task a bit.
I've looked at some similar posts (1), but haven't been able to apply any solution to the code below.

1. [Send signal when attributes modified - QGIS 2.6](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132030/send-signal-when-attributes-modified-qgis-2-6)

enter

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtGui import  *

list_editable_layers = [layer1, layer2, layer3]

def openProject():  
    # list the layers to listen to for edits 
    editLayers  = list_editable_layers
    for l in editLayers:
        # Update feature attributes when new features are added or geometry changes
       l.featureAdded.connect(updateFeatureAttrs)
        l.attributeValueChanged.connect(updateFeatureAttrs)
        l.geometryChanged.connect(updateFeatureAttrs)


def updateFeatureAttrs( fId, geom=None ):
    # how do you pass the layer that cuased the signal to this function?
    editLayer   = iface.activeLayer()

def saveProject():
    pass

def closeProject():
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a class that stores the layer and connects the signal slots.
Something like this:

Save this to My_Editable_Layer.py

```
class My_Editable_Layer():
    def __init__(self, layer):
        # Store the layer in the class field _mLayer
        self._mLayer = layer
        self.connectSignals()

    # A method that add/connect signals on this layer
    def connectSignals(self):
        self._mLayer.featureAdded.connect(self.uppdateFeatureAttrs)
        self._mLayer.attributeValueChanged.connect(self.uppdateFeatureAttrs)
        self._mLayer.geometryChanged.connect(self.uppdateFeatureAttrs)

    # This is the method that runs when the above connected signals is emitted
    def uppdateFeatureAttrs(self, fId, geom=None):
        # You have access to which layer by the class field
        print(f"{self._mLayer.sourceName()} edited")
```

And in your plugin(?) add

```
from My_Editable_Layer import My_Editable_Layer

list_editable_layers = [
    My_Editable_Layer(layer1),
    My_Editable_Layer(layer2),
    My_Editable_Layer(layer3)
]
```